# Н и НН в наречиях

Tags: наречие

Всем привет. Почему в слове медленно, НН? В наречии столько Н, сколько и в прилагательном, в данном случае прилагательное медленный, который, как я думал пишется медлеНый (образован от глагола медлить, одна Н). Объясните пожалуйста в чем я не прав?

Answer (score 3):

ПОРЯДОК ВЫБОРА Н И НН В ПРИЧАСТИЯХ И ОТГЛАГОЛЬНЫХ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ

ПОСТАНОВКА ЗАДАЧИ. Согласно грамматике, для образования полных причастий  используются суффиксы НН и ЕНН, то есть в полных причастиях всегда пишется НН. Что касается отглагольных прилагательных, то там присутствуют суффиксы Н,  НН, ЕН, ЕНН (их значения в грамматике уточняются) Получается, что, даже отличив причастие от прилагательного путем грамматического анализа,  мы все равно НЕ РЕШАЕМ орфографическую задачу выбора Н или НН.

ПРАВИЛО 4-Х ПРИЗНАКОВ. Поэтому  для упрощения используется ФОРМАЛЬНОЕ правило 4-х признаков (наличие приставки, зависимого слова, суффикса ОВА/ЕВА, совершенного вида глагола). По этому правилу грамматический анализ вообще не проводится: мы не различаем причастия и прилагательные и не определяем значения суффиксов отглагольных прилагательных. При наличии признаков пишем две буквы НН, а при отсутствии - одну Н.

ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ.

Однако формальное правило не может охватить все случаи и поэтому неизбежны ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ. По этому правилу пишутся прилагательные со значением РЕЗУЛЬТАТА действия, которые имеют парное причастие: крашеный забор - крашенный в прошлом году забор. Но существует группа прилагательных со значением ОБЩЕГО ОТНОШЕНИЯ к действию, там пишутся суффиксы НН и ЕНН: нежданный, негаданный,  неслыханный, невиданный,  нечаянный, отчаянный, МЕДЛЕННЫЙ,  священный,  деланный, беспрестанный.

Также интересно отметить группу отглагольных прилагательных, в которых  отсутствует гласная в суффиксе, а УДВОЕНИЕ НН происходит на стыке морфем, как и для отыменных прилагательных:  чеканить – чеканный, бранить – бранный, чваниться – чванный, жеманиться – жеманный.

Answer (score 0):

Медленный образовано с помощью суф. -ЕНН-, в котором всегда НН (кроме ветреный)

Comment: Так слово же произошло от глагола, или для слов образованных от глагола действуют те-же правила?